# Angular JS 2 production app "getOwnMetadata is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, angular

I built an Angular 2 application for production, the **dist** directory and it's content (bundle.js, etc..) has been generated successfully but, unfortunately sometimes on the first page load i get the following error message on console and the page does't load:

```
 main.9b6e2b3….bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: hi.getOwnMetadata is not a function
        at main.9b6e2b3….bundle.js:1
        at Object.r [as a] (main.9b6e2b3….bundle.js:1)
        at Object.CI55 (main.9b6e2b3….bundle.js:1)
        at e (main.9b6e2b3….bundle.js:1)
        at Object.UZPW (main.9b6e2b3….bundle.js:1)
        at e (main.9b6e2b3….bundle.js:1)
        at Object.xpih (main.9b6e2b3….bundle.js:1)
        at e (main.9b6e2b3….bundle.js:1)
        at Object.Iksp (main.9b6e2b3….bundle.js:1)
        at e (main.9b6e2b3….bundle.js:1)
```

When i reload the page for second time the error has gone away. I have no idea why is this issue present in application. There is no another error or warning on console.

I used this starter project: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter.

Comment: Can you provide the source code?

Comment: unfortunately i can't provide the whole source code it is too long... but the dev website is available online. (i can send the dev url)

Comment: What are you using webpack or systemjs? because `bundle.js` comes with these two.

Comment: i'm using webpack

Comment: Refer here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11590